# IAD Test ads dont work in 4.2 or 4.3 on device or simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4, iad

I cant seem to make the test ads work for anything other than 4.1 or 4.0 in the simulator. I downloaded the iAdSuite sample code from apple, and still can't get it to work under 4.3/4.2. I don't think the problem is with my code. could there be anything else that could cause this error?

Comment: sorry, i guess i could have been clearer

Answer (score 1):

a) if you have questions whether your code is wrong...you should post your code

b) have you looked at the responses your iAd delegate is receiving? often times I receive 'no inventory available' even for test ads.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code is fine. i can't even get the sample code from apple to run under 4.3/4.2. I get "Ad inventory unavailable" for 4.2/4.3 and "iAd: Did receive ad" for 4.0/4.1.

Comment: take a look at the line that reads [_adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50]. try changing to [_adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait]; (or the correct identifier for your orientation). I believe the former was deprecated and could be causing the problem. The latter was causing a memory problem at one point so you'll have to test it out.

Comment: changing to ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait didn't seem to help.

Comment: have you tried on an actual device? at this point, I would also edit your post to include your code so people can review it. It's hard to give guidance without seeing what exactly is being done.